# Action Script 3. How to remove child which is created from another function?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, parent-child, children

I have added child with function **first**, and I need to remove It with function **third**.

```
function first(event:MouseEvent):void {
   addChild(test); //here add child
   button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, second); //here add listener to second function
}

    function second(event:MouseEvent):void {
       third(event); //here I call third function 
}

   private function third(event:Event):void {
       removeChild(test); //here should delete child, but I got error
}
```

But I got following error: `ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.` How to remove child successfully? Could you help me, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways. First, keep a reference to the clip that you've add:

```
_private var clip:Sprite;

public function first():void {
    addChild(clip);
}

public function second():void {
    removeChild(clip);
}
```

Having the clip that you add/remove as a variable help you to use it in multiple functions. But if there is some problem with that - like not using classes and having code in multiple places, you can always use the `name` property:

```
public function first():void {
    var child:Sprite = new Sprite(); // create new instance so it's not visible anywhere
    child.name = 'myFancySprite';
    addChild(child);
}

public function second():void {
    var child:Sprite = getChildByName('myFancySprite') as Sprite; // get it
    removeChild(child); // remove it
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I misunderstood your first way with reference, I think that is what I tried, but your second method with names worked for me. Thank you!